# xslt find child node with same attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I’ve a strange situation:

### XML

```
...
<item>
    <p><a href="image-01">image X</a>text...</p>
    <p>text...<a href="image-02">image Y</a></p>
    <p>some...<a href="image-02">image y2</a></p>
    <img id="image-02" />
</item>
...
```

I must find the  tags with the same attribute @href (if exist) and add to the first an extra attribute (like class="xyz")
Is it possible??? 
Thank you
sorry for grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="by-href" match="*[@href]" use="@href"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@href][. is key('by-href', @href)[1]]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'xyz'"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime.